# Is the Qwiic connector just a standard JST?

Tags: components, design, wiring

I am using the Adafruit [vl6180x](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3316) and want to produce my own cables for it instead of the ones that Adafruit have on their site.

I could not find the Qwiic/STEMMA connector and pins on the web, nor their specifications. The Adafruit does not sell unassembled wire connectors or pins, and does not present their datasheet on the site. [The only piece of information they had put out](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4399) is parenthesis that say that they have an SH 4 pin 1mm.

Are they the same as the [JST sh 4 pin SHR-04V-S-B connector and SSH-003T-P0.2-H pins](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSH.pdf?5ec58813d214e)?

Comment: explore the Adafruit website ... find the schematic diagram of the module ... it contains the name of the connector ... using that name, find the technical description of the connector on the Adafruit website

Comment: I went over the datasheet thurouhgly before asking the question. They only have the board- side connector as a single unit. they sell the wire side connector as an assembly (assembled connector with crimped pins). all of whom are without datasheet. I want to purchase them individually because I require different wire lengths and insulation. icn see here (https://www.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/common-jst-connector-types/#ph) that the sh 4pin 1mm connectors extremely resemble the quicc ones but I dont have a data  shhet.

Comment: @jsotola I found the schematics, and, sadly, they do not provide the connector type in there. The connector's part number is simply listed as `STEMMA_I2C_QT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ordered jst connectos and tested them on the adafruit's boards.
The connectors are the same and can be used instead of the ones on the assembled wires adafruit sells.

Answer (score 1):

The product page for [STEMMA QT cable assemblies](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4209) (which is their standard used with this board) includes a link to [JST SH connectors](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/index.php?series=231) as the ones used.

For pinouts and such, you can see the [STEMMA QT](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-adafruit-stemma-qt/technical-specs) specification page.

Unfortunately, for this stuff, you can't always rely on the datasheet including the info, or even existing.

Edit:

I just realized, I just went through exactly the same info you have in your question - and thus, why did you ask? JST SH is JST SH, I highly doubt they would have different pitch or keying types labeled as the same series.

Comment: I wonder, does Adafruit skip datasheets and rely on product pages because they're targeting hobbyists?

Comment: I think so. I think I will just order some generic jst sh.